# How to stop style overwriting in wpf?

Tags: xaml, wpf-controls

I create a WPF UserContorl and create a style for ListView in my UserContorl theme.

My ListView Style :

```
<Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="ReminderListView">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Style="{StaticResource ReminderCheckBox}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="{Binding Title, Mode=OneTime}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My ListView Style Work Correctly in UserContorl.

My used Xaml in UserControl:

```
<ListView Name="snoozeListView" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ReminderListView}"  ItemsSource="{Binding ReminderItems}" >
```

i use this UserControl in other WPF project which have a ListViewItem Style.

ListViewItem Style :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource ForegroundBrush}"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2,0,2,0"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                <StackPanel SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Margin="2,0,2,0">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid" Background="Transparent">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="SelectedRect" IsHitTestVisible="False" Fill="{StaticResource SelectedBackgroundBrush}" Opacity="0"/>
                        <GridViewRowPresenter Height="Auto" Margin="2"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Now ListViewItem style overwriting the ListView ItemTemplate Style which defined in user control theme.

How can i stop overwriting.

Comment: If you're just wanting to change a few specific pieces of the template but keep the rest then use BasedOn : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style.basedon.aspx

Comment: dear Chris W, it wasn't helpful. i want to stop this overwriting.